# Javacard get applet AID of installed applets through Java code

Tags: java, javacard

I have a javacard and it has 2 applets installed. Now I would like to select one among the two. Currently how I do is that, I provide the cap file of the applet from which I get its AID. But I don't find this method satisfactory. So

1. Is there a way or steps to get the AID of the applets installed in a java card without having the cap file?
2. Is there a way to select the applet without its AID? By this I mean that is there a way to make an applet auto selectable after reset?
3. Are there any other ideas or insights over this?

Answer (score 6):

For the questions you have asked,

1. Yes. [PyApduTool](http://javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38) can make you reach you goal. This tool can help you get all the packages' or applets'AID in java card even though you don NOT have the cap file.
   Just press the "Refresh" button. the things you need appears in the right text field.

[image]

2. You can set you applet as "Default Selected" when installing it.
   In this way, you can make you applet selected by default without having to know its AID.

[image]

3. For convenience, it should be better to know the applet-AID.
   Only one applet can be the default selected.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same by java code? Cause I have a software code that would load and install applets into a java card and I would like to do it using code.

Comment: Yes, you can use java code to achieve your goal, you need to follow the below steps:
1. implement Secure Channel related instruction;
2. implement the instruction to get package list on card;
3. implement the instruction to install the applets instance.
Check GP specification for more information.Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Andy is good but i feel that its missing an important part of the question:

> Javacard get applet AID of installed applets **through Java code**

If the question refers to finding installedf Applets from the code of one java card applet itself than this answer might apply:
First, it is possible to get the AID of the applet itself by `JCSystem.getAID()`.
Second, it is not possible to "detect" other applets from within an installed applet.
Although if you know the other applet's AID you can get a hack of useful information about it using `JCSystem` and `GPSystem`.

So apart from inside JavaCard code, the Card Manager is able to list of installed applets with all their privileges and so on. You can use a tool of your choice. If you are working with JCOP, I recommend JCOP Shell. If you work with freeware I recommend [Global Platform Pro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) from Martin Paljak.

Beside selecting AIDs and default selection there is no direct way to select an applet. There is an indirect way by using the SharedObjectInterface mechanism from JavaCard which lets you change control flow to a different applet.

Comment: Although I agree that getting the AID's through the card manager wasn't explained by Andy, I think we should stress that the APDU interface to the applets and Global Platform is language agnostic. As long as you obtain a GP library or tool - in whatever language - you can do what is required in the question.